# linux apache python cgi error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python

Tags: python, apache, cgi

My old CentOS 5 apache server can run Perl script CGI without any problem.

```
# cat t1.cgi
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header;

print "Test\n"; 



# GET HTTP://www.example.com/cgi/t1.cgi
Test
```

python scripts can be run under shell without any problem:

```
# cat t2.cgi
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

print("Content-Type: text/html\n")


print("hello!")

# python3 t2.cgi                                                                                                                                                              
Content-Type: text/html

hello!
```

but failed as a python cgi script:

```
# GET http://www.example.com/cgi/t2.cgi
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>An Error Occurred</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>An Error Occurred</H1>
500 Internal Server Error
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

apache error logs show the error was:

```
Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
Python runtime state: preinitialized

Premature end of script headers: t2.cgi
```

any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by

```
mknod -m 444 /dev/random
chmod 444 /dev/urandom
```

my old centos don't have /dev/random, and the default file mode for urandom was 600, read only by root.